# OutofBoundsException running geonames on Android

Tags: android, geonames

I have a simple problem that I can't seem to figure out.  I am trying to execute a geoname WebService.search method and keep getting a "java.lang.StringIndexoutOfBoundsException" error.  I ran the program under plain old Java and it works fine with no problem.  I run it under Android and I get the "java.lang.StringIndexoutOfBoundsException" error.  I have "Internet" permissions set in my manifest.  The error occurs when the Webservice.search(searchCriteria) is executed.  Here is the code:

```
package fau.edu;

import org.geonames.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainRoutine extends Activity {

 TextView displayObject;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        displayObject = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01); 

        try {
        String displayString;
        //
        // Toponomy Search
        //
        ToponymSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new ToponymSearchCriteria();
        searchCriteria.setQ("Miami"); 
        searchCriteria.setFeatureClass(FeatureClass.valueOf("H"));
        searchCriteria.setCountryCode("US");
        searchCriteria.setAdminCode1("FL");
        searchCriteria.setFeatureCode("spng");
        WebService.setUserName("******"); // username '*' out for public consumption.  Actual code has valid name.
        ToponymSearchResult searchResult = WebService.search(searchCriteria);
        displayString = null;
        for (Toponym toponym : searchResult.getToponyms()) { 
         displayString += toponym.getName() + " " + toponym.getCountryName() + "\n"; 
        }
        displayObject.setText(displayString);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         displayObject.setText("Try Error...\n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The failure occurs when I execute the WebService.search(searchCriteria) method.  The error that I get in LogCat is:

```
  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1646
     at org.jdom.input.SAXHandler.startElement(SAXHandler.java:568)
     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.startElement(ExpartParser.java:146)
     ....
```

I have correctly put jdom.jar and geonames.-1.0.6.jar in my Java build path, so I don't think there is a problem there.  The interesting thing is that have re-written the code to use WebService.postalCodeSearch(postalSearch) and WebService.weatherIcao("KPBI") and it works perfectly in Android with no issues.  Like I said, this code runs all day under Java SE6.  Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the substring function somewhere? The error seems to imply that you are trying to read a substring index that does not exist (an index that is e.g. bigger then the string.length()).

Comment: No, at least I don't think so.  The error occurs when the WebService.search method is executed.  Like I said before, it works running under Java SE6 but not on Android.  I can also get different method within the WebService class to work like WebService.postalCodeSearch() and WebService.weatherIaco().

Comment: Could it be something silly like webservice being used from another class in Android, and not the one you needed? Maybe use the full name (I don't know that code, guessing it's supposed to be something like `org.geonames.webservice()`.    That's a really wild guess btw, don't know much else to do :)

Comment: I tried org.goenames.WebService.search() but did not have any luck.  Not sure what to do from here other than start going through the source.  geonames did provide source to there .jar's.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Ok, problem solved.  Not sure what the root cause is but I was running and AVD 2.1.  I deleted this AVD and reloaded the latest AVD from the Android site and created a new AVD 2.3.  The application ran the first time I tried it!  Thanks to all of those who viewed this problem or offered solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. Not sure what the root cause is but I was running and AVD 2.1. I deleted this AVD and reloaded the latest AVD from the Android site and created a new AVD 2.3. The application ran the first time I tried it! Thanks to all of those who viewed this problem or offered solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4286) bug in android 2.1 which has been fixed since 2.2.  I've experienced the same issue using the geonames client library.  To fix the problem use [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader/downloads/detail?name=jdom-1.1.1-android-fork.jar) fork of JDOM.